# Dynamic Javascript Array .length

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

What I'm trying to do is push new ".post" (which have been retrieved by the infinite-scroll script) into my array which holds all of the ".post".

Full Code: https://gist.github.com/sxxfi/8296403 
Live Demo: http://soof-show.tumblr.com (navigate through posts with keyboard arrow keys)

Initially, five ".post" show up in the ".content" div, then each time the 'MORE' button is clicked it adds 5 more ".post" to ".content".

The problem is the array length doesn't count for the new ".post" so it keeps looping the first 5.

Thank you in advance if you're able to help solve this.

**Javascript:**

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

        // I N F I N I T E  S C R O L L
        $('.content').infinitescroll({
          navSelector  : ".navigation",
          nextSelector : ".navigation .next_page",
          itemSelector : ".content .post",
          behavior: "twitter"
        });

        $(window).unbind('.infscr');

        $('.next_page').click(function(){
          $(document).trigger('retrieve.infscr');
          return false;
        });

        $(document).ajaxError(function(e,xhr,opt){
          if (xhr.status == 404) $('.next_page').remove();
        });


        // I M A G E  S L I D E R
        var obj = $(".post");
        var arr = $.makeArray(obj);
        var lastDiv = $(".post");
        var indexNum = arr.length-1;

        $(window).keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 37) { // L E F T
                lastDiv.fadeOut(800);
                indexNum--;
                if (indexNum == -1) indexNum = arr.length-1; //if goes beyond first post, goto the last post
                $(arr[indexNum]).appendTo(".postslide").fadeIn(800);

                // C E N T E R
                var width = $(arr[indexNum]).width();
                var marginLeft = width / 2;
                $(arr[indexNum]).css('margin-left', -marginLeft);
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 39) { // R I G H T
                $('#instruction').fadeOut();
                lastDiv.fadeOut(800);
                indexNum++;
                if (indexNum == arr.length) indexNum = 0; //if goes beyond last post, goto the first post
                $(arr[indexNum]).appendTo(".postslide").fadeIn(800);

                // C E N T E R
                var width = $(arr[indexNum]).width();
                var marginLeft = width / 2;
                $(arr[indexNum]).css('margin-left', -marginLeft);
            }
        });

    });
```

**UPDATE:**

```
        $(document).ready(function(){


        // I N F I N I T E  S C R O L L
        $('.content').infinitescroll({
          navSelector  : ".navigation",
                         // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
          nextSelector : ".navigation .next_page",
                         // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
          itemSelector : ".content .post",
                         // selector for all items you'll retrieve
          behavior: "twitter"
        });

        // kill scroll binding
        $(window).unbind('.infscr');

        // manual click 
        $('.next_page').click(function(){
          $(document).trigger('retrieve.infscr');
          return false;
        });

        // remove the paginator done
        $(document).ajaxError(function(e,xhr,opt){
          if (xhr.status == 404) $('.next_page').remove();
        });




        // I M A G E  S L I D E R
        var obj = $(".post");
        var indexNum = obj.length-1;
        var lastDiv = $(".post");



        $(window).keydown(function (e) {

            if (e.keyCode == 37) { // L E F T

                lastDiv.fadeOut(800);
                indexNum--;
                if (indexNum == -1) indexNum = obj.length-1; //if goes beyond first post, goto the last post
                $(obj[indexNum]).appendTo(".postslide").fadeIn(800);

                // C E N T E R
                var width = $(obj[indexNum]).width();
                var marginLeft = width / 2;
                $(obj[indexNum]).css('margin-left', -marginLeft);
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 39) { // R I G H T

                $('#instruction').fadeOut();
                lastDiv.fadeOut(800);
                indexNum++;
                if (indexNum == obj.length) indexNum = 0; //if goes beyond last post, goto the first post
                $(obj[indexNum]).appendTo(".postslide").fadeIn(800);

                // C E N T E R
                var width = $(obj[indexNum]).width();
                var marginLeft = width / 2;
                $(obj[indexNum]).css('margin-left', -marginLeft);
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: I don't see where you're adding anything to the array.

Comment: @Barmar That's what I need help with, I'm unsure how to add to the array. I tried using push but that didn't work so I took it out the code.

Comment: I also don't see where you're getting the 5 new posts, so I can't figure out where you want to add the new elements to the array. Should I be looking at the live demo instead of the question to see what you're talking about?

Comment: @Barmar Yeah if you 'inspect element' via Chrome on the live demo you can see the new posts being generated in the "content" div

Comment: Does the infinite scroll widget let you supply a callback when the new elements have been added? That's where you need to add to the array.

Comment: @Barmar good point, I'm looking into it now: https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/search?q=callback&type=Issues

Comment: Guessing that `didEndLoading` is what you want.

Comment: @Barmar hmm, I'm not sure how to invoke `didEndLoading`

Comment: Add `didEndLoading: function() { ... }` to the infinite scroll options.

Comment: @Barmar still loops the first five :(

Comment: Can you update the question to show your new code? Don't erase the original code, add it as an UPDATE section at the end.

Comment: Where is the `didEndLoading` code?

Comment: @Barmar I added it into the infinite scroll script: http://static.tumblr.com/sogtvrs/ZANmz1uge/jquery.infinitescroll.js

Comment: You were supposed to add it to the options argument in `$('.content').infinitescroll({`

Comment: @Barmar I tried, gives an error 'unexpected token' on didEndLoading

Comment: I'll bet you forgot to add a comma after `"twitter"`.

Comment: @Barmar I actually didn't

Comment: You made some kind of syntax error when you added it. If you post what you did, maybe I'll be able to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery selectors query the DOM at the moment the jQuery function is called, so they select the elements matching the selector at the given moment.

Even if new elements that should match your selector are added to the DOM later, they will not get selected as nothing notifies jQuery to reevaluate the selector, and even if something did, jQuery has no inner state holding all the jQuery objects created. This means that the selectors are [not live](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/#jquery-objects-are-not-quot-live-quot).

Your main problem here is that you never update the array of selected DOM elements so even when new elements are added to the DOM you still loop over the original array.

Updating the jQuery object is easy, you just need to recall `obj = $(".post")` at any time in your code, and the `obj` variable gets updated. We just need to figure out when to call it.

Since you are using [Infinite Scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) to load new elements we need to look at it's [documentation](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/wiki/_pages), or since the documentation currently has large holes in it, it might be better to look at the [source code](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/blob/master/jquery.infinitescroll.js).

Look at the `infinitescroll` function:

```
$.fn.infinitescroll = function infscr_init(options, callback) {
    ...
```

The second parameter is called `callback` and upon examining the source code and the way this parameter is passed and called, you can see that it will be called after new elements were retrieved. Let's try this parameter out:

```
$('.content').infinitescroll({
    navSelector : ".navigation",
    // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
    nextSelector : ".navigation .next_page",
    // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : ".content .post",
    // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    behavior: "twitter"
}, function () {
    obj = $(".post");
    console.log("Current length is: " + obj.length); //this line is not necessary, just here for debug purposes.
});
```

Assuming that variable `obj` already exists this will update it's value.

Note that in a previous version of this answer I called this callback function `recountPosts()`. I have decided later that it can simply be an inline anonymous function since it will be only called from one place.

You are nearly finished, but... you have other variables depending on this selector. Namely `arr` and `lastDiv`. Upon examining your source code it seems that none of them are necessary:

1. `arr` is an array made from the elements selected by the jQuery object and although the [jQuery object is not an array](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/), it has a zero based numeric indexer and a length property *just like an array*, so you can substitute `arr` with `obj` anywhere in your code.
2. `lastDiv` has a misleading name. It holds the same elements as `obj` not just the last. Therefore it can also be substituted with `obj`.

So the part where you declare your variables can be shrunk to:

```
// I M A G E  S L I D E R
var obj = $(".post");
var indexNum = obj.length-1;
```

I have also looked at your `keydown` event handler. There is a lot of duplicated code in it. This is prone to introduce bugs later on (in fact you already have a bug: if you press left instead of right at the start, the initial picture of the keyboard will not disappear).

Let me restructure it for you a little bit:

```
$(window).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) { // L E F T
        indexNum--;
    }

    if (e.keyCode === 39) { // R I G H T
        indexNum++;
    }

    if (e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 39) {
        $('#instruction').fadeOut();

        obj.fadeOut(800);

        if (indexNum === -1) {
            indexNum = obj.length-1; //if goes beyond first post, goto the last post
        }
        if (indexNum === obj.length) {
            indexNum = 0; //if goes beyond last post, goto the first post
        }

        $(obj[indexNum]).appendTo(".postslide").fadeIn(800);

        var width = $(arr[indexNum]).width();
        var marginLeft = width / 2;
        $(obj[indexNum]).css('margin-left', -marginLeft);
    }
});
```

And it is done!

---

No, of course it is not done. It is far from done, there is still many, *many* things to improve.

- Like removing the ugly recalculation of `margin-left` on every keypress and solve it with a few lines of css. As a thumb rule: if something can be solved in css instead of javascript it should be.
- Or like calling `infinitescroll(...)` on `$(".postslide")` instead of `$(".content")` and removing the completely unnecessary `.appendTo(".postslide")` from before `fadeIn()`, as the elements are already appended and it is a waste of resouces to reappend them.
- Or moving constants, like the 800 ms fade length to the beginning of the code giving them a variable like `var fadeLength = 800;` and use it.

And I'm pretty sure there are lot of other things that could be done better, but that is just how programming is :)

[Have fun coding!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4COLV6CleU)

### EDIT:

So you also want the more button only to appear if you are at the end of the slides. You have written this:

```
if (indexNum === 14){
  $('.next_page').html('<img src="http://long_url/">');
}
```

Why do you hard-code 14 into the source? Why do you even care on how many pictures are loaded and how many will load? The given part of the code need only to know if you are at the end. If you have a variable on how many slides are loaded, you can easily check if you are at the last index. You *do* have that variable, the `obj.length`:

```
if (indexNum === obj.length-1){
  $('.next_page').html('<img src="http://long_url/">');
}
```

This way the more button will appear on the last slide not caring if it's the 30th, 45th or 9001st.

You would also need this button to disappear after new content has been loaded. This goes into the callback of infinitescroll:

```
function () {
    obj = $(".post");
    console.log("Current length is: " + obj.length); //this line is not necessary, just here for debug purposes.
    $('.next_page').html('');
}
```

---

An other thing you could do is instead of showing the more button, you could trigger the more event from code. This way the new slides get loaded automatically when the user reaches the last slide.

Also this only needs to happen if there are actually more slides to load. You can check the current state's `isDone` property, which tells you if the "infinite scroll is done" so there are no more elements to load.

```
$('.content').data('infinitescroll').options.state.isDone === false
```

So instead of the part that shows the more button, you could just write this:

```
if (indexNum === obj.length-1 && !$('.content').data('infinitescroll').options.state.isDone){
  $(document).trigger('retrieve.infscr');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped simplify my code. However it is still looping the first five posts, even after adding `recountPosts();` to the handler of the MORE button.

Comment: I can't see the obj variable updated anywhere in the live demo you linked. Are you sure you update it? Also you should know, that you don't even need the `lastDiv` variable and can simply call `obj.fadeOut(800);`

Comment: I was trying different things with the live demo, I just updated it back now, let me know what you see

Comment: Nonono. You added the line in question AFTER the `return`! It will never be executed! Also since the event is an async call, the given line will possibly run before the pictures are loaded.

Comment: Oh it seems it was not clear what I intended. Now you don't trigger the event. I'll try to clear up my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the keydown restructure by the way. I updated the live demo to edit 2, still looping the five.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe the "postslide" div is causing the problem

Comment: Yes I noticed an other thing blocking the reevaluation: You are hiding the obj variable in the `recountPosts()`. You are writing `var obj = ...` instead of just `obj = ...`.

Comment: The event handlers are running in opposite order. Now if you press more twice it will loop 10 pictures.

Comment: It is because it calls recountPosts() first, then adds all the new elements. On the next click, the elements added from the previous click are already there. I'm sure this `infinitescroll` plugin has a decent callback somewhere which will execute after the elements are loaded, just need to find it.

Comment: There is some family crisis going on now, so I have to go. I'll get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: No worries, I really appreciate your help! Talk to you tomorrow.

Comment: I have completely restructured my answer. Please see if it works for you.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you! I simplified the code to append to ".content" instead. One last thing, Tumblr loads 15 posts at a time max and I want the "more" button to appear on the final post (in this case every 15th one) so I added: `if (indexNum === 14){
             $('.next_page').html('<img src="http://static.tumblr.com/sogtvrs/s4Emz3za5/more.png">');
           }` Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: I'll edit my answer on that. By the way can you change `$(obj[indexNum]).appendTo(".content").fadeIn(800);` to `$(obj[indexNum]).fadeIn(800);`? The `.appendTo(".content")` part is completely unnecessary now.

Comment: I replaced the 'more' code with what you suggested but I'm not sure what you mean by 'query the state'. It doesn't seem to load the new posts.

Comment: It was just bad wording. I meant checking the state. Edited it to be (hopefully) more clear.

Comment: Added a part about hiding the more button after load.

Comment: the more button load is working smooth! I updated my code on http://soof-show.tumblr.com/ to the automatic load but it isn't working, I tried a few different ways.

Comment: Never mind the last part about automatic loading. I would have to play around with the code a little bit to know why it isn't working. You are well off with the more button.

Comment: I think it may just be the infinite-scroll script, it's meant to be trigged on scroll and I added a plugin to trigger it on click. Once again, I can't thank you enough for your help, wish I could give you more rep points haha.

Comment: hm, is it possible to make the more button fadeOut on the callback?

Comment: You mean like `$('.next_page img').fadeOut(800);`?

Comment: Hey @SoonDead, I have a further question regarding this code. Let me know if you have time. Cheers ~

Comment: @digimane This is a Q&A site, so it is always an option to make a new question. If you reference that question in the comments here, I will try my best to answer that too. Or we could move this discussion to chat, but since we live in a very different timezone, I doubt it would be very productive.

Comment: Anyway [here is the link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46202/dynamic-javascript-array-length) to the chat room, and now you also have the reputation (at least 20) to join.

Comment: I just missed you, now I'm there.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

You are setting value as soon as page loads and not updating it when scroll happens or at other key bindings

**Solution:**

```
    // I M A G E  S L I D E R
        var obj = $(".post");
        var arr = $.makeArray(obj);
        var lastDiv = $(".post:last");
        var indexNum = arr.length-1;


        $(window).keydown(function (e) {
                        obj = $(".post");
                        arr = $.makeArray(obj);
                        lastDiv = $(".post:last");
                        indexNum = arr.length-1;

                        //other code

        });
```

Comment: Just call `obj = $(".post");` again.

Comment: `obj` isn't an array, it's a jQuery object.

Comment: The OP said _my array which holds all of the ".post"._

Comment: In your answer you re-assign `arr` and `indexNum`, but you don't re-assign `obj` first.

Comment: @RohitAgrawal the slider gets stuck on the first post with the updated code.